# how is DMA-capable memory defined?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma

When literature describes DMA concepts and operations, it usually says about DMA-capable memory. My questions are:

1. Is this memory defined at boot-up time, for instance by BIOS or in case with embedded platform -- by the bootloader?
2. Is DMA-capable memory region platform specific?
3. If I implement a Linux device driver and want it to use DMA, can I be sure that DMA memory is set up and configured for me by the kernel/bootloader, so I have to only worry about implementing read/write transactions over bus?

Thanks.

Comment: What part of the [documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt) do you not understand?

Comment: @CL, thanks for the link. One thing I don't understand is that kmalloc returns a virtual address, which can be used for DMA operations, but in my understanding DMA works with physical addresses. How then it understand kmalloc addresses?

Comment: The *memory* returned by `kmalloc()` can be used for DMA, but only after DMA-mapping the virtual address.

Comment: Normally all the available memory can be DMA-able, however on old systems only the first 16Mb could be used for DMA (ISA devices, probably early PCI), am I right? So now there's no such a restriction?

Comment: The DMA mapping function will use the IOMMU if the memory is not accessible from the device's bus; you can avoid this by using special flags when allocating memory (`DMA`, `DMA32`), or using the DMA memory allocation functions. However, DMA with most 'normal' devices should work.

Comment: Also check `dma_alloc_coherent()` et al.